# Odd dispatch_sync crash

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to debug a crash that occurs to a few users of my application, infrequently and in a non-reproducible manner.

The stack looks like this:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 objc_msgSend
1   libdispatch.dylib               _dispatch_client_callout
2   libdispatch.dylib               _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke
3   com.myapp.CorePlayer            -[PreoutWorker cancel] + 89
```

The `[PreoutWorker cancel]` method looks like this:

```
- (void)cancel {
    dispatch_sync(_workerQueue, ^{
        if ([self isExecutingI]) {
            ++self -> _act;
            [self -> _device stop];
            [self resetI];
        }
    });
}
```

The application makes significant use of threading, but all of the other threads are either idle or doing unrelated things.

The `PreoutWorker` object presents a `thread safe interface` to its clients (they always call it on the main thread.) Internally it dispatches work to `_workerQueue` which is a serial dispatch queue.

It seems to me that the only way the `cancel` method could generate this crash would be if the `objc_msgSend` was one of the calls within the block passed to `dispatch_sync`.

The header doc for `dispatch_sync` suggests this may be possible, but is frustratingly vague about the details:

> * As an optimization, dispatch_sync() invokes the block on the
>   current
>   * thread when possible.

Does anyone have any knowledge of exactly what "when possible" means in this context?

Comment: The crash is probably diagnostic. `cancel` would then be a red herring. http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html